# Google Cloud Messanger, "More acks than expected"

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-messaging

Every once in a while I get a message on the server from the client that looks something like this:

```
INCOMING MESSAGE!!!!!!!!!!!!
<message id='2u650-31' to='xxxxxxxxxxx@gcm.googleapis.com/Smack0152E3A3' type='error'><error type="cancel"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Received more acks than expected.</text></error><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;to&quot;:&quot;ClientsRegistrationIDGoesHere&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;1054919404&quot;,&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;ack&quot;}</gcm></message>
GCM PACKET
com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient$GcmPacketExtension@6454f46b
JSON
{"to":"ClientsRegistrationIDGoesHere","message_id":"1054919404","message_type":"ack"}
```

After this error I get a stack trace that looks like this:

```
WARNING: Not connected anymore, echo message is not sent
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:584)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient.send(SmackCcsClient.java:106)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(SmackCcsClient.java:84)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient.handleUpstreamMessage(SmackCcsClient.java:228)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient$2.processPacket(SmackCcsClient.java:409)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(XMPPConnection.java:1233)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection$ListenerNotification.run(XMPPConnection.java:1143)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Oct 08, 2014 10:36:01 PM com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient$2 processPacket
SEVERE: Failed to process packet
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:584)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient.send(SmackCcsClient.java:106)
    at com.bannervision.web.controller.admin.SmackCcsClient$2.processPacket(SmackCcsClient.java:415)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(XMPPConnection.java:1233)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection$ListenerNotification.run(XMPPConnection.java:1143)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The error that pops doesn't seem to effect anything else, everything keeps sending and coming in as it should but after this error start popping, it will continue every 5 seconds.

**Question**
How do I catch this error? The error only appears in the xml.  Shouldn't this be considered a nack message?
or
Better yet how do I prevent it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These error are most definitely related.  My problem was that I was calling a connection every time I sent a message out.  This occurred because I replaced Google's main method and did not form a connection on compile but rather a connection on send.

I added this (`@PostConstruct` is specific to spring):

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception{
        try {
            smackCcsClient.connect(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("gcm.api")), env.getProperty("gcm.key"));
        }catch (IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SmackException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(XMPPException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then never call connect again.  The only other time connection is used is when a message is accepted.  All send messages use the same connection.  This was a major over site on my behalf.